# Add divs on top of an div, when hovering

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I'm currently trying to do so when you hover over an element, three divs will overlay the element here's an example of what I want it to do.

Left side is not hovered, the right side is hovered.

[image]

I realized that this is not possible to do in css, but I believe this can be done in jQuery, first I tried adding classes but that is not going to work the way i want it to, I'm completely lost when it comes to jQuery.

```
$(function() { 
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ikon').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('hover'); 
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });
```

Currently css who handles the pictures:

```
/**PORTFOLIO-ALBUM***/
/*==================*/

#portfolio #album {
    width: 955px;
    min-width: 360p;
    height: 780px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 250px;
}

#portfolio .ikon {
    width: 280px;
    height: 175px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

#portfolio .ikon img {
    max-width: 350px;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -35px;
    top: -10px;

}
```

How pictures get outputted:

```
    $query = "SELECT photo_id, photo_filename FROM photos WHERE fk_photo_category_id = '$album_category' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($result->num_rows  > 0) {

        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $photo_name = $row['photo_filename'];
        $photo_id = $row['photo_id'];

        echo "<div class='ikon'><a href='index.php?page=portfolio.php&album=$album_id&photo=$photo_id'><img src='img/photos/$photo_name' alt='' /></a></div>";

        }
```

Comment: what is the way you want it to work?

Comment: @erkaner as soon as I hover, the effect on top of the secound picture is going to appear. I also updated the picture, to couse less confusion.

Comment: Personally, I would use jQuery for this, but it could also be done with just HTML/CSS. The `:hover` pseudo-class is quite versatile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS solution using absolute positioning and z-indexes if CSS isn't completely off the table.

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ggaqxy)

```
.initial {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.initial:hover {
    z-index: 0;
}

.hover-div-container {
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.hover-div-container:hover {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a very solid solution!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the event .hover() it bind one or two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.'. Link - [Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Seems like this is what you need.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: You need to expand on your answer so that it includes the main details of what is in the link. Without the link, it's not a substantial answer. Future searchers will get to feel like a yo-yo, arriving here and bouncing off elsewhere - which may be dead, or may be of no use to them. So you need those details.

Comment: ok.. I am new to stackoverflow and next time I will remember your advice.

Comment: You can use the edit link under your answer to improve it now.

Comment: Yes. As you get more experience answering, and looking at answers, you can always revisit and improve. Look out particularly for new versions, techniques which may be useful, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the z index of a div like this.

```
<div>
    <div class="some_class">
        original div
    <div>
    <div class="hover_class"
        div that shoud appera
    <div>
<div>

Now in Css
#portfolio .iKon {
    z-index:1
 }
#portfolio .iKon:hover {
    z-index: -1; #it will make the original div go in background
}
.hover_class{
    z-index:0;
}
```